# Javascript: Problem of javascript file import in yarn build

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I have two JavaScript codes.

I would like to import and use another one from one javaScript code.

I tried a few things to import, but there was an error.

This is my main code(main.js):

```
    import * as test from "./noise";

    const audioContext = new AudioContext({sampleRate: 48000});
    const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

    await NoiseNode.register(audioContext)
```

And, This is the code that I want to import(noise.js):

```
    window.NoiseNode = (window.AudioWorkletNode || (window.AudioWorkletNode = window.webkitAudioWorkletNode)) &&
    class extends AudioWorkletNode {
        static async register(a) {
            k = await h;
            await a.audioWorklet.addModule(g + "other.js");
        }}
```

If i try to import as below,

```
import * as test from "./noise;
```

These errors occur:

```
Line 141:15:  'NoiseNode' is not defined  no-undef
```

and then, If i try to import as below,

```
import * as NoiseNode from "./noise";
```

These errors occur:

```
Attempted import error: 'register' is not exported from './noise' (imported as 'NoiseNode').
```

How can I get everything at once?

Please give me some advice.

Thank you.

Comment: The code you've shown us doesn't contain the word `export` anywhere. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export NoiseNode before importing it.

```
export window.NoiseNode = (window.AudioWorkletNode || (window.AudioWorkletNode = window.webkitAudioWorkletNode)) &&
```

after exporting, you may import it using the following code:

```
import * as NoiseNode from "./noise";
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I know how to solve it.